# are the relation can be any arbitary subset of cartesian product..

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having a doubt about relations...

It is said any mapping from A to B or any subset  of $A\times B$ is the relation from A to B.

But we should we able to define the how the mapping is defined?. In any arbitary subset of $A\times B$ how will we define the mapping...

I mean..Suppose $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3, 4\}$ the relation set $R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$ can be defined as a mapping $R=\{(a,b):a=b\}$.

But what about the subset $R=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,3),(3,2),(4,4)\}$, this is also a subset of $A×B$ but is it a relation, if so how is the mapping defined can you say...Or how can I write this set in set builder form?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Not every relation can be represented with a mapping (your last example would not be a mapping from $ A $ to $ B $ because $ 1 $ would be mapped to two distinct elements, which is not allowed for a mapping).  But every mapping $ f : A \rightarrow B $ can be represented by a relation via $ R = \{ (x, f(x)) \mid x \in A \} \subseteq A \times B$.

Not every set can be represented in "builder notation".  Sometimes the best way to represent a set is to list its elements as you did.

Comment: So the relation from A to B is just any subset of $A×B$..

Comment: @mathstudent yes, but your textbook should declare definitions like this for you, there shouldn't be any need to ask.